# How could I convert this to c++

Tags: c#, c++

I've written c# code for a registry modifying application, but the problem is c# is easily reversible and obfuscators make the program look like malware. So my problem is that I can't find anything close to `Registry.SetValue` for c++. Any help is appreciated.

I've tried using a c# to c++ tool by tangible but it was bad and it didn't work as expected at all.
I've also tried RegSetValueEx but I think I used it incorrectly.
This is what I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HKEY key;
    if (RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion"), &key) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << "unable to open registry";
    }

    if (RegSetValueEx(key, TEXT("value_name"), 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)"value_data", strlen("value_data")*sizeof(char)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        RegCloseKey(key);
        cout << "Unable to set registry value value_name";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "value_name was set" << endl;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Could someone explain what is value_name value_data and how to use it with an example as that is the main thing I'm confused with.

Comment: `RegSetValueEx` is how you modify registry in Windows.

Comment: What do you mean you *"think [you] used it incorrectly?"*  Can you [edit] in what you tried, and what happened?  Consider reading through [ask] for tips on well-formed questions.

Comment: Just so you know, an interested hacker doesn't even need to look at the code to figure out what registry parameters your code sets - an API logger will show that.

Comment: What could your code do that is so super-secret that you don't want anyone to reverse it?

Comment: There is no need for such secretiveness.  Make the registry key something that even if a hacker would see it, it would be indecipherable, so much so that fooling around with the value will make your app stop or not work in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use RegSetValueEx - all C++ wrappers for the registry are very thin wrappers around the simple C API.

Comment: yea, but could you give an example since I've tried myself and failed

Comment: @NobieSCSGO the rules of StackOverflow are that the person asking the question must provide a minimal example of what they tried. [mcve] So you are required to give the example first so that we can figure out what you did wrongly and better answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HKEY key;
    RegOpenKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, TEXT(""), &key);
    LPCTSTR value = TEXT("");
    LPCTSTR data = TEXT("");
    LONG setRes = RegSetValueEx(key, value, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)data, _tcslen(data) * sizeof(TCHAR));
    RegCloseKey(key);

  return 0;
}
```

this solved it